# Possible to add property to object in array in blockopertion (AFNetwork)?

Tags: ios, nsarray, addition, afnetworking

I'm making several request from different sources, and because of this I want to add a property like:  '"newsSource" = twitter' (JSON format)  to the created NSArray resultsTwitter below. The reason is I want be able to handle each "newsitem" uniquely.

I'm new to blocks, but I think it might be an really easy way to do this "on the fly"?
*If not possible within the block operation, any suggestion on how to do it after operation is done?*

```
    // Fetch data from Twitter (json complient)
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlTwitter];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                            success:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *responce, id jsonObject) {
                                                                NSLog(@"Responce: %@",jsonObject);
                                                                self.resultsTwitter = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"results"];
                                                                [self.tableView reloadData];    
                                                            }
                                                            failure:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *responce, NSError *error, id jsonObject) {
                                                                NSLog(@"Recieved an HTTP %d", responce.statusCode);
                                                                NSLog(@"The error was: %@",error);
                                                            }];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not have understood your question correctly, but as long as `resultsTwitter` is a `NSMutableArray`, you can add an object (in your case an `NSDictionary` with a single KVP) after it is initially populated.

Something like:

```
[resultsTwitter addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"twitter", @"newsSource",
                            nil]];
```

Example of instantiating a variable that can be accessed inside a block:

```
__block NSString *newssource = @"";

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlTwitter];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                            success:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *responce, id jsonObject) {
                                                                NSLog(@"Responce: %@",jsonObject);
                                                                self.resultsTwitter = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"results"];
                                                                [self.tableView reloadData];
                                                                newssource = @"twitter";


                                                            }
                                                            failure:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *responce, NSError *error, id jsonObject) {
                                                                NSLog(@"Recieved an HTTP %d", responce.statusCode);
                                                                NSLog(@"The error was: %@",error);
                                                            }];

[operation start];
```

Comment: Thanks ElJay, good tip "almost" what I want. But I'm actually looking to add a **property** to an object and populate that property "newssource" with content "twitter". And if not possible within the block then after the operation finished and iterate through all objects and add this property to them all. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: You can add a variable and preface it with __block to be able to retrieve and update inside a block. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Nice! Do I understand this correctly, that this will add the newssource property to every object, directly as they are fetched before they are put into the array?

Comment: Tried it but don't seems to work. (Would be nice if it did though! I get this object after using the above; '{
            "created_at" = "Mon, 22 Oct 2012 16:37:06 +0000";
            "from_user" = rtswiz;
            "from_user_id" = 230652170;
            "from_user_id_str" = 230652170;
            "from_user_name" = "Sam DeRoy";
            geo = "<null>";
            id = 260419518105526274;
            "id_str" = 260419518105526274;
            "iso_language_code" = en;
           // etc but no new property news source...
            };
        },
'

Comment: Btw: does maybe the array need to be an NSMutableArray for this to work? (now it's just an NSArray).

Comment: UPDATE: Nope did not make any difference.

Comment: I guess I don't understand.  Are you wanting to modify the that is populated inside the block?

Comment: The block gets all the twitter data and each tweet becomes a object, just when before the object is created and added to the resultsTwitter array - then I want to add a newssource property to the object. Then do the same to every object that is created in the block.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model class to encapsulate the behavior of all News Items.

This pattern is used in the AFNetworking example app, with each App.net post corresponding to a model object, which is initialized from JSON. I would strongly recommend against using a mutable dictionary rather than a model object as a means of representing items.